# Can't get AJAX POST request formatted correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

No matter what I do, I keep getting `500 (Internal Server Errors)` when attempting to perform a `POST` to `https://rates.tradelanes.us/bankaccount/record/create`. I believe its the format of my data, but when I compare what my output is to others trying the same thing--my data format is identical; others are not getting the `500 error`, so it must be how my data is formatted. The only documentation I have with the API is https://rates.tradelanes.us/bankaccount/help/api--so not much more to go on.

[Here is the error I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL1jh.jpg). If you wanted to see what a sample record looks like:

```
{"Id":1,"Memo":"Sample Record","Amount":10.00,"TransactionDate":"\/Date(1503500694627)\/","Account":1,"Transaction":0}
```

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table_records = $("#table_records").dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "https://rates.tradelanes.us/bankaccount/records",
      dataSrc: ""
    },
    "columns": [{
      "data": "Id"
    }, {
      "data": "Memo"
    }, {
      "data": "Amount"
    }, {
      "data": "TransactionDate"
    }, {
      "data": "Account"
    }, {
      "data": "Transaction"
    }]
  });

  //Show popup for creating new record
  function show_lightbox() {
    $(".lightbox_bg").show();
    $(".lightbox_container").show();
  }

  //Hide popup for creating new record
  function hide_lightbox() {
    $(".lightbox_bg").hide();
    $(".lightbox_container").hide();
  }

  //Clicking the "Close" button or outside of the lightbox should close the lightbox
  $(document).on("click", ".lightbox_bg", function() {
    hide_lightbox();
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".lightbox_close", function() {
    hide_lightbox();
  });

  //Handle clicking the "Create" button
  $(document).on("click", "#createButton", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".lightbox_content h2").text("Create record");
    $("#form_create button").text("Create record");
    $("#form_create").attr("class", "form add");
    $("#form_create").attr("data-id", "");
    $("#form_create .field_container").removeClass("valid").removeClass("error");
    $("#form_create #id").val("");
    $("#form_create #memo").val("");
    $("#form_create #amount").val("");
    $("#form_create #transactiondate").val("");
    $("#form_create #account").val("");
    $("#form_create #transaction").val("");
    show_lightbox();
  });

  function getFormData($form) {
    var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
    var indexed_array = {};

    $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i) {
      indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });

    return indexed_array;
  }

  //Handle form submission
  $(document).on("submit", "#form_create.add", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hide_lightbox();

    var $form = $("#form_create");
    var form_data = getFormData($form);
    console.log(form_data);

    var req = $.ajax({
      url: "https://rates.tradelanes.us/bankaccount/record/create",
      cache: false,
      data: form_data,
      dataType: "application/json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      type: "post"
    });

    req.done(function(out) {
      if (out.result == "success") {
        table_records.api().ajax.reload(function() {
          alert("Record added successfully");
        }, true);
      } else {
        alert("Record failed to be created");
      }
    });

    req.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666;
}


/* General -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

* {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input,
button,
select {
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #666;
}

button,
select {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=number],
input[type=email],
input[type=url],
input[type=password],
input[type=date],
input[type=search],
input[type=tel] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 none !important;
}


/* Page container ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#page_container {
  width: 980px;
  padding: 40px 5px 55px 5px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}


/* Header --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

button.button {
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #999;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

button.button:hover,
button.button:active {
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Datatable ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

.dataTables_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
}

.dataTables_length {
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 110px 0 0;
}

.dataTables_length label {
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dataTables_length select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #666;
  padding: 0 50px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dataTables_length:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #999;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  content: '\f107';
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.dataTables_length select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.dataTables_filter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.dataTables_filter label {
  line-height: 30px;
}

.dataTables_filter input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #666;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.dataTables_filter input:focus {
  background-color: #ffd;
}

.dataTables_paginate {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.dataTables_paginate a {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #999;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.dataTables_paginate a.current,
.dataTables_paginate a:hover,
.dataTables_paginate a:active,
.dataTables_paginate a:focus {
  background-color: #333;
}

.dataTables_paginate a.previous,
.dataTables_paginate a.next {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.dataTables_paginate a.previous:before {
  content: '\f104';
}

.dataTables_paginate a.next:before {
  content: '\f105';
}

.dataTables_info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
}

table.datatable {
  width: 100% !important;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
}

table.datatable th,
table.datatable td {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

table.datatable thead th {
  background-color: #999;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

table.datatable thead th.sorting,
table.datatable thead th.sorting_desc,
table.datatable thead th.sorting_asc {
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.datatable thead th.sorting:active,
table.datatable thead th.sorting_desc:active,
table.datatable thead th.sorting_asc:active {
  background-color: #333;
}

table.datatable tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #eee;
}

table.datatable tbody tr:hover th,
table.datatable tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: #ffd;
}

table.datatable tbody tr:hover td.dataTables_empty {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table.datatable tbody td.company_name {
  width: 100%;
}

table.datatable tbody td.integer {
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.datatable tbody td.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.datatable tbody td.functions .function_buttons {
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

table.datatable tbody td.functions .function_buttons li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

table.datatable tbody td.functions .function_buttons li.function_delete {
  padding: 0;
}

table.datatable tbody td.functions .function_buttons a {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #999;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 29px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

table.datatable tbody td.functions .function_buttons .function_edit a:before {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  content: "\f040";
}

table.datatable tbody td.functions .function_buttons .function_delete a:before {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 30px;
  content: "\f1f8";
}

table.datatable tbody td.functions .function_buttons a:hover,
table.datatable tbody td.functions .function_buttons a:active,
table.datatable tbody td.functions .function_buttons a:focus {
  background-color: #333;
}

table.datatable tbody td.functions .function_buttons span {
  display: none;
}


/* Lightbox ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.lightbox_bg {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lightbox_container {
  display: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #666;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.lightbox_close {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 45px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f70;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #f70;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  -moz-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.lightbox_close:before {
  content: '\f00d';
}

.lightbox_close:hover {
  color: #333;
  border-color: #333;
}

.lightbox_content {
  width: 642px;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

.lightbox_content h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  color: #f70;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container:after {
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  content: ' ';
}

.lightbox_content .input_container label {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container label span.required {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f70;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container .field_container {
  width: 400px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container .field_container label.error {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff1e6;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px 0 6px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f70;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container .field_container label.error.valid {
  display: none !important;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container .field_container input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #666;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container .field_container input:focus {
  background-color: #ffd;
  color: #000;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container .field_container.error:after,
.lightbox_content .input_container .field_container.valid:after {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -42px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container .field_container.error:after {
  content: '\f00d';
  color: #c00;
}

.lightbox_content .input_container .field_container.valid:after {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: #090;
}

.lightbox_content .button_container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 15px 0 50px 0;
}

.lightbox_content .button_container button {
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #999;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.lightbox_content .button_container button:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Message / noscript --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#message_container,
#noscript_container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#message_container {
  display: none;
}

#message,
#noscript {
  width: 980px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 6px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#message p,
#noscript p {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 28px;
}

#message p:before,
#noscript p:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f70;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#message.success p:before,
#noscript.success p:before {
  content: '\f00c';
}

#message.error p:before,
#noscript.error p:before {
  content: '\f00d';
}


/* Loading message ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

#loading_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  text-align: center;
}

#loading_container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#loading_container3 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#loading_container4 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  color: #666;
  padding: 165px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#loading_container4:before {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f70;
  content: '\f013';
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Bank CRUD</h1>
    <button type="button" class="button" id="createButton">Create record</button>
  </div>

  <div id="tableDiv">
    <table class="datatable" id="table_records">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Memo</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Transaction Date</th>
          <th>Account</th>
          <th>Transaction</th>
          <th>Functions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="lightbox_bg"></div>

  <div class="lightbox_container">
    <div class="lightbox_close"></div>
    <div class="lightbox_content">

      <h2>Create record</h2>
      <form class="form add" id="form_create" data-id="" novalidate>
        <div class="input_container">
          <label for="id">Id: </label>
          <div class="field_container">
            <input type="number" id="id" min="0" class="text" name='"Id"' value="" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input_container">
          <label for="memo">Memo: </label>
          <div class="field_container">
            <input type="text" id="memo" class="text" name='"Memo"' value="" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input_container">
          <label for="amount">Amount: </label>
          <div class="field_container">
            <input type="number" id="amount" min="0" class="text" name='"Amount"' value="" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input_container">
          <label for="transactiondate">Transaction Date: </label>
          <div class="field_container">
            <input type="text" id="transactiondate" class="text" name='"TransactionDate"' value="" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input_container">
          <label for="account">Account: </label>
          <div class="field_container">
            <input type="number" id="account" min="0" class="text" name='"Account"' value="" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input_container">
          <label for="transaction">Transaction: </label>
          <div class="field_container">
            <input type="number" id="transaction" min="0" class="text" name='"Transaction"' value="" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button_container">
          <button type="submit">Create record</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: getFormData() isn't returning JSON, it's returning an object.

Comment: how do I convert it to JSON then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to apparently remove all of the `settings` for the AJAX request. Who would have guessed?

So it should look like the following:

```
var req = $.ajax({
      url: "https://rates.tradelanes.us/bankaccount/record/create",
      dataType: "json",
      data: form_data,
      type: "POST"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to be sure that you are getting the form .

```
let form = $('.whatever').find('form');
```

and then pass the data as the serialized form

```
form.serialize()

var req = $.ajax({
      url: "https://rates.tradelanes.us/bankaccount/record/create",
      cache: false,
      data: form.serialize(),
      dataType: "application/json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      type: "post"
    });

    req.done(function(out) {
      if (out.result == "success") {
        table_records.api().ajax.reload(function() {
          alert("Record added successfully");
        }, true);
      } else {
        alert("Record failed to be created");
      }
    });
```